# download apps (in Windows) from apps.ubuntu.com

Tags: downloads

As I can't connect from Ubuntu 12.04 to internet, I want to download apps from Windows XP system and then install to Ubuntu (offline). Any app page I visit, all I see is a link to download Ubuntu and nothing else.

Is it mandatory to visit from Ubuntu itself ?

Googling never even gives any such questsion/answer. I don't know why no one even bothers to ask it or maybe I'm doing the most stupidest thing! I'm ok to list out dependencies one by one and downloading each one of them.

Still I'm left helpless. `apt-get` is a distant fantasy and that WILL NOT work for me!

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Cube](https://launchpad.net/camicricube)**. It is an offline package management system and runs in both Linux and Microsoft Windows.

**Cube Running in Windows XP**
[image: Cube on Windows]

Download it in [Cube Launchpad Page](https://launchpad.net/camicricube) , and check the CubeTutorial.pdf first to know how it works and how to run it in Linux and Windows. Still under development and currently in its 1.0.7 BETA Version. I hope that this will solve your problem.